# Process crash and file locks

Tags: file, process, locking

I would like to ask about file locks in a context of process crash.

Let's say we run a process under Linux that holds some locks and this process is terminated by e.g. segfault. The question is: is it possible that some file locks will be left after the crashed process?

Thanks for response in advance

Comment: Which operating system?  I would take a very quick guess that if a process crashes it released the locks however it is never that simple.  I had a quick google and this was interesting, partially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651068/release-of-flock-in-case-of-errors

Comment: @n34_panda Thanks for the link, it is for Linux.

Comment: Yeah after re-reading I saw that (woops).  There is a lot of information available....