# what happens with FileLock on JVM crash?

Tags: java, java-7, filelock

I'm just wondering what happens with a lock from FileLock, if a JVM crashes hard or it gets a SIGKILL.

Nothing in the [FileLock doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) is specified about it, so I assume it is released. 
Just want to make sure, though...

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the same as with any other program that crashes, which is platform dependent. As the [api doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) states, FileLock just uses the native locking mechanism available on the platform you run on:

> This file-locking API is intended to map directly to the native
>   locking facility of the underlying operating system.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12652718/261142) to a similar question.